# RMarkdown: Tables with math notation and long text within

Tags: r, r-markdown

First, I gotta say I'm a total beginner using `RMarkdown`.

Said that, I've been introducing myself into that world in order to learn how to make reports. By now I learned the basics (math notation, some text formatting) but I can't create tables the way I've done in the past.

I've already created a table using `knitr::kable()` but without math notation:

[image]

````
```{r table1, echo=F, warning=FALSE, message=F}

library(knitr)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
text_tbl <- data.frame(
        'Nro'=1:2,
        'Obj'= c(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id dolor id arcu pellentesque ullamcorper sit amet sit amet tortor. Quisque quis ligula non turpis faucibus rhoncus. Vestibulum lacinia laoreet massa eget semper.   ",
                "Phasellus aliquam mauris dui, id sagittis velit blandit sit amet. Etiam posuere elementum magna, eu fermentum dolor aliquet vitae. Maecenas ultricies orci quam, eu ultricies augue efficitur non. Suspendisse ligula diam, luctus quis tempus et, venenatis in orci.  ")
)

kable(text_tbl, 'latex', 
      booktabs=T,
      caption = 'Table example') %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
  column_spec(2, width = '14cm')
```
````

Now I want to reproduce this table:

[image]

The first table's approach wouldn't work as this new table includes math notation.

I tried pipe tables but the third column is too long and won't work (seems it only works with short text inside the table) and something odd happens with math notation.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `escape` to `FALSE` in `kable` to type math equations.

```
text_tbl <- data.frame(
    'Nro'=1:2,
    'value' = c("a = $\\frac{1}{2}$", "b = $\\frac{2}{3}$"),
    'Obj'= c(
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id dolor id arcu pellentesque ullamcorper sit amet sit amet tortor. Quisque quis ligula non turpis faucibus rhoncus. Vestibulum lacinia laoreet massa eget semper.   ",
            "Phasellus aliquam mauris dui, id sagittis velit blandit sit amet. Etiam posuere elementum magna, eu fermentum dolor aliquet vitae. Maecenas ultricies orci quam, eu ultricies augue efficitur non. Suspendisse ligula diam, luctus quis tempus et, venenatis in orci.  ")
)

kable(text_tbl, 'latex', 
  booktabs=T, escape = F, 
  caption = 'Table example') %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position", full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
  column_spec(3, width = '14cm')
```